# Is it possible to dynamically select between two different template files for the same content type?

Tags: theming, nodes

We are rolling out changes on a content type with a new theme and field structures for existing content.

Is it possible to dynamically select one of two template files for a content type?

For example, if a field on the content type is checked then use node--product.html.twig but otherwise use node--product-old.html.twig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can implement [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter(](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/9.2.x)) to set up different templates based on the field.

In your case, you want to add templates for nodes, so the theme hook is `node`. As such, you would implement the following:

```
function hook_theme_suggestions_node_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->hasField('some_field') && $node->some_field->value == 1) {
    $suggestions[] = 'node__product';
  }
}
```

With this code, when `some_field` does not exist, or does not have a value of `1`, the default `node.html.twig` template will be used, and when `some_field` has a value of `1`, the template `node--product.html.twig` will be used. Adjust accordingly.

Comment: Awesome. I did not know theme suggestions could be used in that way. Thank you!

Comment: It's exactly what they're used for :) It's a very powerful part of the theming layer. Good luck!